# Optional parameters in SSRS 2008

Tags: sql, reporting-services

If anyone could help me out with this it would be greatly appreciated.

I have a query that is pulling our sales data that I want to put into an SSRS report.Shown here:

```
SELECT SH.[CompanyKey]
  ,[DeliveryDate]
  ,[CustomerKey]
  ,AcAccounts.ShortDesc
  ,SH.[ItemKey]
  ,ITEM.ItemDesc
  ,[InvoiceDate]
  ,[SalesRep1Key]
  ,[SalesRep2Key]
  ,[ReturnCancelCode]
  ,[ShipToKey]
  ,[BillToKey]
  ,[RouteNo]
  ,[PaymentTypeKey]
  ,[DeliveryTypeKey]
  ,[OrderNo]
  ,[OrderDate]
  ,[OrderStatus]
  ,[PostingPeriod]
  ,[Quantity]
  ,[QuantityUnit]
  ,[QuantityConvFactor]
  ,[OldOrderNo]
  ,[OrderVersionNo]
  ,[PONumber]
FROM 
[Company].[dbo].[FactSalesHistoryDS] SH
INNER JOIN [FRESHWAY].[dbo].[DimFiAcAccounts] AcAccounts ON
AcAccounts.AccountKey = SH.CUSTOMERKEY
INNER JOIN [freshway].[dbo].[dimitem] ITEM ON
SH.ItemKey = ITEM.ItemKey
WHERE INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND SH.ItemKey = @ItemKey
```

I presently have it organized by item number which is working fine but I would also like this report to have the option of having a parameter of customer key so that I can either run the report per customer or per item. Is this possible to do in the same report or do I need to just create to reports: Sales by Item and Sales by Customer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using a case statement in your where.  Say you have a parameter called @CustomerKey and it is nullable along with the @ItemKey which is also nullable.  Your select would then be laid out like:

```
SELECT SH.[CompanyKey]
  ,[DeliveryDate]
  ,[CustomerKey]
  ,AcAccounts.ShortDesc
  ,SH.[ItemKey]
  ,ITEM.ItemDesc
  ,[InvoiceDate]
  ,[SalesRep1Key]
  ,[SalesRep2Key]
  ,[ReturnCancelCode]
  ,[ShipToKey]
  ,[BillToKey]
  ,[RouteNo]
  ,[PaymentTypeKey]
  ,[DeliveryTypeKey]
  ,[OrderNo]
  ,[OrderDate]
  ,[OrderStatus]
  ,[PostingPeriod]
  ,[Quantity]
  ,[QuantityUnit]
  ,[QuantityConvFactor]
  ,[OldOrderNo]
  ,[OrderVersionNo]
  ,[PONumber]
FROM 
[Company].[dbo].[FactSalesHistoryDS] SH
INNER JOIN [FRESHWAY].[dbo].[DimFiAcAccounts] AcAccounts ON
AcAccounts.AccountKey = SH.CustomerKey 
INNER JOIN [freshway].[dbo].[dimitem] ITEM ON
SH.ItemKey = ITEM.ItemKey
WHERE INVOICEDATE BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate
AND SH.ItemKey = CASE WHEN @ItemKey IS NOT NULL THEN @ItemKey ELSE SH.ItemKey END
AND SH.CustomerKey = CASE WHEN @CustomerKey IS NOT NULL THEN @CustomerKey  ELSE SH.CustomerKey END
```

Comment: thats exactly what I needed! Thanks!

For some reason drew a blank about using a case statement.